# Function based on multiple image sources

Tags: javascript

I cannot seem to get this function to check multiple image sources on click and run a sound to work, is there something I am doing wrong?

```
function victory() {
    if (document.getElementById("Image0").src == "0.jpg" &&
        document.getElementById("Image1").src == "1.jpg" &&
        document.getElementById("Image2").src == "2.jpg" &&
        document.getElementById("Image3").src == "3.jpg" &&
        document.getElementById("Image4").src == "4.jpg" &&
        document.getElementById("Image5").src == "5.jpg" &&
        document.getElementById("Image6").src == "6.jpg" &&
        document.getElementById("Image7").src == "7.jpg" &&
        document.getElementById("Image8").src == "8.jpg" &&
        document.getElementById("Image9").src == "9.jpg")
    {
    document.getElementById("vic").currentTime = 0;
    document.getElementById("vic").play();
}
```

Comment: `Image4t`? Looks like a typo. Also, you appear to be missing a closing bracket (`}`).

Comment: Not the case but thanks for the quick reply

Comment: @AshadShanto: Don't "Fix" code in the OP, it may well be the source of the problem.

Comment: can you post the html

Comment: Wouldn't a loop from 0 to 9 would be clearer?

Comment: Not strictly "wrong", but the `if` block can be refactored and be made less verbose (using a function argument of valid file names and a loop). If one of the images do not exist on the page then you will get an error, as well (accessing `.src` on `undefined`, something like that).

Comment: could you tell us what returns `document.getElementById("ImageX").src`? i mean, do you test that its getting what you expected?

Comment: they work ive tested the get element id because i have functions that change the source which work for all the images, its just that when all the images become green i want a victory sound to go, the only html i have added is onclick="victory()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working for me:
http://jsfiddle.net/29y5346m/1/

```
function victory() {
    if (document.getElementById("Image0").src.indexOf("0.jpg") != -1)
    {
        document.getElementById("vic").currentTime = 0;
        document.getElementById("vic").play();
    }
}
```

Things you may have wrong:

- "}" on the end is missing (for function victory())
- image.src can have a route prefix for a given image, use indexOf instead. That way you search in the string for that name